# make single generic service among these two

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics

I have two static classes along with static method in each of it. I am doing some database operations(single Insert) in each of method in those classes as mentioned in below

**Class A:**

```
public static class ClassA
{
    public static Guid UpsertRequest(
      InputA inputa,
      MasterSection masterSection,
      RequestInput requestInputs,
      APIDbContext dbContext)
    {
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

        var libraryA = new LibraryA
        {
            Id = id,
            InitialRevisionId = inputa.InitialRevisionId ?? id,
            MasterSection = masterSection,
            DirectExhaust = inputa.DirectExhaust,
            Revision = 0
        };

        dbContext.LibraryA.Add(libraryA);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        var request = RequestHelper.CreateRequest(masterSection, libraryA.Id, requestInputs, dbContext);
        dbContext.Requests.Add(request);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return request.Id;
    }
}
```

**Class B:**

```
public static class ClassB
{
    public static Guid UpsertRequest(
      InputB inputb,
      MasterSection masterSection,
      RequestInput requestInputs,
      APIDbContext dbContext)
    {
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

        var libraryB = new LibraryB
        {
            Id = id,
            InitialRevisionId = inputb.InitialRevisionId ?? id,
            MasterSection = masterSection,
            AirClass = inputb.AirClass,
            Revision = 0
        };

        dbContext.LibraryB.Add(libraryB);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        var request = RequestHelper.CreateRequest(masterSection, libraryB.Id, requestInputs, dbContext);
        dbContext.Requests.Add(request);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return request.Id;
    }
}
```

i am looking generic way to combine  these two service classes or implementing any abstract class out of this and could not be able to figure it out how to do this. I can be able to change the static to normal class as well.

Could any one suggest any ideas on how to make generic out of it that would be very grateful to me 
many thanks in advance

**Update**

I am calling these two methods from those classes like as below

```
public InsertMutationResponse UpsertMethodA(
      LibraryInputA InputA,
      RequestInput requestInputs)
    {
        var ok = false;
        var errors = new List<string>();
        var requestId = default(Guid);

        if (requestInputs != null)
        {
            var masterSection = _dbContext.MasterSections.SingleOrDefault(
                ms => ms.Name == requestInputs.MasterSection);                
                requestId = ClassA.UpsertRequest(
                    InputA,
                    masterSection,
                    requestInputs,
                    _dbContext);
                ok = true;           
        }
        return new InsertMutationResponse(ok, errors, requestId);
    }
```

This is how i am calling **class B** method

```
    public InsertMutationResponse UpsertMethodB(
      LibraryInputB InputB,
      RequestInput requestInputs)
    {
        var ok = false;
        var errors = new List<string>();
        var requestId = default(Guid);

        if (requestInputs != null)
        {
            var masterSection = _dbContext.MasterSections.SingleOrDefault(
                ms => ms.Name == requestInputs.MasterSection);                
                requestId = ClassB.UpsertRequest(
                    InputB,
                    masterSection,
                    requestInputs,
                    _dbContext);
                ok = true;           
        }
        return new InsertMutationResponse(ok, errors, requestId);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to move logic in common generic method? Does both logics will change for same reason when some changes need to be applied to the logic?

Comment: yeah, I am looking to move that logic to common generic method, i have 7 classes more same like as below

Comment: If you extract request creation into dedicated method (only similar part in both methods) - you will be good to keep both methods

Comment: inputa and input b...do they inherit from a base class (with id and initialrevision fields)?  feel like that base class would need a property that would return your directexhaust/airclass thing...the librarya and libraryb probably need a base class for either common functionality as well...and should that directexhaust/airclass thing be a single field...that feels like a type field id guess

Comment: is there any possible to extract remaining parts into common as well

Comment: they do inherit from same interfaces but not the base class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible to implement it this way and there is more options how to simplify, but it really is up to your needs.

```
public interface ILibrary
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public abstract class Class<TInput, TLibrary>
   where TLibrary : ILibrary
{
    protected abstract TLibrary CreateLibrary(TInput input, MasterSection masterSection);

    public Guid UpsertRequest(
      TInput input,
      MasterSection masterSection,
      RequestInput requestInputs,
      APIDbContext dbContext)
    {
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

        var library = CreateLibrary(input, masterSection);

        dbContext.Set<TLibrary>().Add(library);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        var request = RequestHelper.CreateRequest(masterSection, library.Id, requestInputs, dbContext);
        dbContext.Requests.Add(request);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return request.Id;
    }
}

public class ClassA : Class<InputA, LibraryA>
{
    protected override LibraryA CreateLibrary(InputA input, MasterSection masterSection)
    {
        new LibraryA
        {
            Id = id,
            InitialRevisionId = input.InitialRevisionId ?? id,
            MasterSection = masterSection,
            DirectExhaust = input.DirectExhaust,
            Revision = 0
        };
    }
}

public class ClassB : Class<InputB, LibraryB>
{
    protected override LibraryB CreateLibrary(InputB input, MasterSection masterSection)
    {
        return new LibraryB
        {
            Id = id,
            InitialRevisionId = input.InitialRevisionId ?? id,
            MasterSection = masterSection,
            AirClass = input.AirClass,
            Revision = 0
        };
    }
}
```

**Update**

After question update I need to update answer too.

I am not having lot of context, but from what I do have/know I would implement it like this.

**Update 2 - based on information provided in chat**

```
public class Whatever
{    
    public InsertMutationResponse UpsertMethodA(
    LibraryInputA inputA,
    RequestInput requestInputs)
    {
        var ok = false;
        var errors = new List<string>();
        var requestId = default(Guid);

        if (requestInputs != null)
        {
             var @class = new ClassA();

            var masterSection = _dbContext.MasterSections.SingleOrDefault(
                ms => ms.Name == requestInputs.MasterSection);                
            requestId = @class.UpsertRequest(
                inputA,
                masterSection,
                requestInputs,
                _dbContext);
            ok = true;           
        }
        return new InsertMutationResponse(ok, errors, requestId);
    }

    public InsertMutationResponse UpsertMethodB(
    LibraryInputB inputB,
    RequestInput requestInputs)
    {
        var ok = false;
        var errors = new List<string>();
        var requestId = default(Guid);

        if (requestInputs != null)
        {
             var @class = new ClassB();

            var masterSection = _dbContext.MasterSections.SingleOrDefault(
                ms => ms.Name == requestInputs.MasterSection);                
            requestId = @class.UpsertRequest(
                inputB,
                masterSection,
                requestInputs,
                _dbContext);
            ok = true;           
        }
        return new InsertMutationResponse(ok, errors, requestId);
    }
}

public interface ILibrary
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public abstract class Class<TInput>
   where TLibrary : ILibrary
{
    protected abstract ILibrary CreateLibrary(TInput input, MasterSection masterSection);

    public Guid UpsertRequest(
      TInput input,
      MasterSection masterSection,
      RequestInput requestInputs,
      APIDbContext dbContext)
    {
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

        var library = CreateLibrary(input, masterSection);

        dbContext.Set<TLibrary>().Add(library);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        var request = RequestHelper.CreateRequest(masterSection, library.Id, requestInputs, dbContext);
        dbContext.Requests.Add(request);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return request.Id;
    }
}

public class ClassA : Class<InputA>
{
    protected override ILibrary CreateLibrary(InputA input, MasterSection masterSection)
    {
        new LibraryA
        {
            Id = id,
            InitialRevisionId = input.InitialRevisionId ?? id,
            MasterSection = masterSection,
            DirectExhaust = input.DirectExhaust,
            Revision = 0
        };
    }
}

public class ClassB : Class<InputB>
{
    protected override ILibrary CreateLibrary(InputB input, MasterSection masterSection)
    {
        return new LibraryB
        {
            Id = id,
            InitialRevisionId = input.InitialRevisionId ?? id,
            MasterSection = masterSection,
            AirClass = input.AirClass,
            Revision = 0
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i have updated the my question where i am calling those classes methods, with your approach how can i call these methods

Comment: You'll make those classes generic too. You'll probably need to pass an instance to your class(es). Can you share whole class. I'll do my best to update those to make it work. Thanks

Comment: Are you using DI?

Comment: i am not using DI, do you mean those input classes

Comment: I mean class(es) where `UpsertMethodA` and/or `UpsertMethodB` methods are implemented. I just want to see how to make it generic. What can be used for all and what not.

Comment: that is big class and i have more methods in it and those ones are not look like these methods

Comment: Okay. I'll just work with what you have shared then. Gimme a few minutes. I'll ping you with update.

Comment: Check the update. In case something it not clear let me know. I'll explain.

Comment: The method `UpsertMethod<TInput>` i am calling from UI and if we need to pass type to this method how can we pass from UI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206644/discussion-between-dropoutcoder-and-enigma-state).

Comment: If i cannot be able to implement ILibraryInput i believe still it is fine right

Comment: Yes. It is possible to do so. You just need to set entity property inside template method which is I believe `CreateLibrary`. In the end you might want to rename it to `CreateEntity`.

Comment: i am getting error at this line  `dbContext.Set<TLibrary>().Add(library);` in `library service file` and the error is `the type TLibrary must be reference type in order to use it as a parameter TEntity in the generic type    DbContext.Set<TEntity>()`

Comment: Oh yeah. It is generic type constraint on `Set` method. Sorry, I didn't realized it. Just put `where TLibrary : class` constraint there.

Answer (score 0):

@Enigma-State If possible, you may care to have a base class (more than likely abstract)  for `LibraryG` from which both `LibraryA` and `LibraryB` are derived, or alternatively, have an interface, `ILibrary` implemented by both `LibraryA`/`LibraryB`.

The same thing needs to be done for `InputA` and `InputB`.

Then have a generic class `ClassG` that will instantiate to either `ClassA` or `ClassB` that will implement a static method `UpsertRequest(..)` with an additional parameter, that is the generic Library, `LibraryG`.  Alternatively, use ClassIG, a hybrid of interface/generics.

This is what I have in mind for `ClassIG` replacing `ClassA` and `ClassB`:

This is what I have in mind for ClassIG:

```
public static class ClassIG<TLibrary>
{
    public static Guid UpsertRequest(
      IInput inputg,
      MasterSection masterSection,
      RequestInput requestInputs,
      APIDbContext dbContext
      TLibrary libraryg)
    {
        // You will need to implement this method so that the correct library is 
        // added to the correct collection.
        AddLibrary<TLibrary>(libraryg);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        var request = RequestHelper.CreateRequest(masterSection, libraryg.Id, requestInputs, dbContext);
        dbContext.Requests.Add(request);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return request.Id;
    }
}
```

With the limited information that I have, this is what I came up with, you should consider your particular case.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I do have different properties that are not common in LibraryA and LibraryB and same as in InputA and InputB